# How to retrieve every "i" from firebase database using (for i=firebase.getChildrencount) i>0 i-- )

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to color every user in different color, so I want to retrieve the user uuid from firebase and send them something.
How can I do it with for(int i....) like in java?

This is my firebase nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

get your database reference :
`mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`  for example.
 then use `child()` to get to the specific elemet `mDatabase.child("user_notifications")` in your case.

now you need to register a listener to read the data , and iterate over your `dataSnapshot` with the method `getChildren()`.
for example :

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot pair : dataSnapshot.getChildren())

          String uid = pair.getKey();
          String token = pair.getValue(); // make sure to cast properly.

    // ...
}
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
}; 
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Take a look at Firebase docs [Read and Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) as well.